# Cpan fails under cygwin with bogus permission error

Tags: cygwin, cpan

Windows 10, current 64-bit Cygwin (CYGWIN_NT-10.0 ddblap7 2.10.0(0.325/5/3) 2018-02-02 15:16 x86_64 Cygwin), Cygwin perl 5, version 26, subversion 2 (v5.26.2) built for x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi (current Cygwin version), cpan version installed with that (all fully up-to-date with Cygwin packages).

First attempt at using cpan on this install (relatively new laptop, I've been using perl on Solaris and Linux and BSD and Cygwin for decades now).

Attempting to install Image-ExifTool fails saying I don't have write permissions.  However, that's bogus; I'm an admin user, and Explorer clearly shows me having write permissions to every file and directory I probed under c:/cygwin64/usr/share/perl5.

The error:

```
$ cpan install Image-Exiftool
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages

CPAN.pm requires configuration, but most of it can be done automatically.
If you answer 'no' below, you will enter an interactive dialog for each
configuration option instead.

Would you like to configure as much as possible automatically? [yes]
Use of uninitialized value $what in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/5.26/App/Cpan.pm line 669, <STDIN> line 1.

Warning: You do not have write permission for Perl library directories.
```

My permissions on a random perl library directory (they all look the same):

[image]

Any ideas?  I can't find any sign of an actual protection issue, though I couldn't tell from the message exactly what file it failed on.  It's a relatively recent Cygwin install, went smoothly enough and I've been using it a lot, but haven't needed to add cpan modules until lately.

(I can't help noticing that everybody has protection issues doing anything with cpan under Cygwin.  I kind of need this on Windows, though, it's for photo work and I need the Adobe toolset and some other things not available for Linux. I end up with cpan perl *anyway*, so I'm working on the theory of use it rather than also maintain simultaneously an Activestate install (and worry about them getting in each other's way.)

Comment: ask cygwin how it sees permissions on that directories and files. Cygwin has its own interpretation of ACL to simulate a PSOX like behaviour.

Comment: Huh, you think they check themselves, rather than just performing the operation and checking if it fails?  Pretty weird way to write software!

Okay, let's see...not looking very interesting

Comment: Can't find any way to invoke code mode (that works here); may have to edit every line of out put individually.

Comment: ctrl-k selects the URL bar, doesn't invoke code mode.  four spaces might work but I'd have to edit each line individually. Backticks don't work despite the docs.

Comment: $ ls -ald *
    drwxr-xr-x+ 1 ddb None 0 May  5 13:37 5.26
    drwxr-xr-x+ 1 ddb None 0 Mar  4 20:10 vendor_perl

Comment: Nope, 4 spaces don't work either. AND they run me out of comment chracters

Comment: So, no formatting, sorry; can't figure out how to make it happen.ddb@ddblap7:/usr/lib/perl5
$ getfacl -v *
getfacl: unknown option -- v
Try `getfacl --help' for more information.
ddb@ddblap7:/usr/lib/perl5
$ getfacl *
# file: 5.26
# owner: ddb
# group: None
user::rwx
group::r-x
other:r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other:r-x

# file: vendor_perl
# owner: ddb
# group: None
user::rwx
group::r-x
other:r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other:r-x

Comment: If you're having trouble formatting things in comments maybe better to just update your question with more details, which you can also do.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I also get the same error immediately preceding it:

```
Use of uninitialized value $what in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/5.26/App/Cpan.pm line 669, <STDIN> line 1.
```

except mine says

```
Use of uninitialized value $what in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/5.30/App/Cpan.pm line 679, <STDIN> line 1.
```

Note first that 'cpan' pulls App::Cpan.pm from /usr/share/perl5, not /usr/lib/perl5 (nor /lib/perl5, which is somehow just a mirror of /usr/lib/perl5).  Also note this is bug is not in CPAN.pm, nor under directory CPAN, but in App::Cpan.

I see from [here](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=107295) that that bug in Cpan.pm was fixed around CPAN 2.25, but /usr/share/perl5/5.30/CPAN.pm is v 2.22 .  I [downloaded the source for the whole CPAN package](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN) & compiled & installed it. That got rid of the "uninitialized value $what" error message, but I still got the "no write permission" message.

Try looking at who cygwin thinks owns that directory, and the usual perl library directory:

```
ls -ld /usr/share/perl5
ls -ld /lib/perl5
```

On my Windows 10 machine, both directories were owned by my Microsoft user.  What I mean is, when you install Windows 10, it wants you to use a Microsoft account to log into your machine that will also log into all your other Windows 10 machines.  I think that's a terrible security risk, so I do everything with just my local account on that machine. But somehow, cygwin saw my Microsoft account as owning my cygwin directory.

However, running

```
for d in bin dev etc lib opt packages tmp usr var; do chown -R me $d; chgrp -R Users $d; done
```

didn't stop the permission error.  It appears that it's best to change permission in Windows; cygwin just can't do it in Windows 10--it often says "Permission denied" for things you have permission for.  But doing that didn't fix it either.

Perhaps the problem is that I installed cygwin as one user, and am trying to use it as another user, and I need to do a full reinstall of cygwin.  I just gave in and chose the [local::lib] option, so my perl libraries will be installed under usr/local/lib/perl5 .

Answer (score 0):

On a default-installed windows 10, you need to run cygwin as administrator in order to install a perl module or permission errors occur.

[image]